Breusch Pagan test in Python
The statsmodels module in Python provides a function to perform the Breusch Pagan test:
statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.het_breuschpagan
The function returns 4 outputs: lagrange multiplier statistic and the relative p-value, and f-statistic and the relative p-value.
I would like to know the difference between the lm statistic and the f-statistic. Are they two different statistics of the same test ? When using the first one instead of the second one and viceversa ?
Might the two different statistics return two different outcomes for the acceptance of the test ?

The Breusch-Pagan test aims to detect heteroscedasticity in a regression model (the presence of non-constant variance in the error terms). The statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.het_breuschpagan function returns the following two statistics (and their p-values) :

Lagrange Multiplier (LM) statistic

F-statistic


Differences Between LM Statistic and F-Statistic
1. Lagrange Multiplier (LM) Statistic

Calculation: The LM statistic is derived from the Lagrange Multiplier test (also known as the score test). It is based on the residuals of the original regression model and the auxiliary regression (where the squared residuals from the original regression are regressed on the original independent variables).

Purpose: The LM statistic tests whether the explanatory variables explain the variance in the residuals.

Distribution: Under the null hypothesis of homoscedasticity, the LM statistic follows a chi-squared distribution with degrees of freedom equal to the number of explanatory variables (excluding the intercept).


2. F-Statistic:

Calculation: The F-statistic comes from an auxiliary regression in which the squared residuals from the original model are regressed on the original explanatory variables. This statistic is essentially derived from the R-squared value of this auxiliary regression.

Purpose: The F-statistic assesses the same hypothesis as the LM statistic but uses the F-distribution for inference.

Distribution: Under the null hypothesis of homoscedasticity, the F-statistic follows an F-distribution with degrees of freedom equal to the number of explanatory variables (excluding the intercept) and the number of observations minus the number of explanatory variables.


Relationship and Usage

Similar Purpose: Both statistics are used to test the null hypothesis of homoscedasticity against the alternative hypothesis of heteroscedasticity. They should provide similar conclusions because they are testing the same hypothesis.

Different Approaches: The LM statistic uses the chi-squared distribution, while the F-statistic uses the F-distribution. These are different approaches to the same problem.

Practical Differences: In large samples, the LM statistic and the F-statistic should lead to similar conclusions. In small samples, the F-statistic might be more reliable because it accounts for sample size through its degrees of freedom.

Different Outcomes for Acceptance of the Test:

Large Samples: In large samples, the results from both statistics should converge, and they should not give meaningfully different p-values.
Small Samples: In small samples, there might be some differences due to the different distributions used (chi-squared vs. F-distribution). This can lead to different p-values and potentially different conclusions about rejecting the null hypothesis. While the F-statistic adjusts for sample size through its degrees of freedom, it is also more sensitive to deviations from assumptions in small samples. Therefore, the F-statistic might be more reliable, but it is crucial to ensure that the assumptions of the test are met. In some cases, alternative methods such as Welch’s ANOVA might be more appropriate.



Practical Recommendation:

Choose Based on Context: If your sample size is large, either statistic can be used, and they should yield similar results. In smaller samples, the F-statistic might be preferable.

Report Both: It's often a good practice to report both the LM statistic and the F-statistic along with their p-values to provide a comprehensive picture of the test results.


Conclusion
While the LM statistic and F-statistic are derived differently, they both aim to test for heteroscedasticity. In most practical applications, especially with large samples, they will give consistent results. However, differences might occur in smaller samples due to the inherent differences in their respective distributions.

In general different tests can have different robustness to misspecification, but this might not be the case here. Example, the wald test in the auxiliary regression could be made robust to heteroscedasticity, while the sum of squares based F-test would always be non-robust to misspecified higher moments. (For variance tests the misspecification/heteroscedasticity could be in the 4th moment under non-normality, i.e. variance of the variance.) Related issues could be when testing several possible hypothesis, e.g. heteroscedasticity test robust to autocorrelation and reverse.

@Josef Good points. Thank you for that :)
